# Only 907 MB detected from 2 GB of RAM by fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

I am new in Fedora (23 workstation).

When I check system monitor apps GUI, they tell me if just 907 MB used by fedora.

My RAM is 2GB

My System information:

`dmesg` → http://pastebin.com/XcxYnW7q

`free -m` → http://pastebin.com/m6QsjrMq

`sudo lshw -short | grep 'System\ Memory'` → http://pastebin.com/2tFgCdqn

Comment: Run a `memtest` at boot; also, you may want to try to reseat your memory banks(s) . Don't be fooled, `lshw` can work properly even if your memory banks are not fully inserted in their slots.

Comment: Its entirely possible fedora is only using 907 mb cause it dosen't need any more.  htop output and/or a screenshot of the GUI the OP's referring to would be handy.